# trouble importing a vue2 component

Tags: javascript, flask, vuejs2

I am including main.js using script tag with type="module".

After running

```
npm install vue2-datepicker --save
```

I try to import it as shown in [docs](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker):

```
import DatePicker from 'vue2-datepicker';
```

And get:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “vue2-datepicker”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”."
```

Here are other ways I tried:

```
import DatePicker from "./vue2-datepicker"
"GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/vue2-datepicker net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

import DatePicker from "./node_modules/vue2-datepicker"
"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

import DatePicker from "./node_modules/vue2-datepicker/index.min.js"
"Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './node_modules/vue2-datepicker/index.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"
```

and more..

File tree:

```
C:.
├───main.js
└───node_modules
    ├───date-format-parse
    │   ├───es
    │   │   └───locale
    │   ├───lib
    │   │   └───locale
    │   └───src
    │       └───locale
    └───vue2-datepicker
        ├───locale
        │   └───es
        └───scss
```

Comment: You don't have a `package.json`? (try `npm init`) How do you start your app too? Where exactly do you import this one?

Comment: @kissu, I ran npm init and now I do have package.json in the same root directory. Same result.. I import my main.js it in my html with  <script src="main.js" type="module"> .

Comment: I'm not sure if you can reference a webpack module through an HTML import tbh. Why don't you use webpack? Any specific limitations?

Comment: Yes, my app is server-side rendered and served by Python's Flask. I do not have a build step for Vue.

Comment: If you don't have a build step for Vue, then I'm not sure how you expect your NPM packages to work. Your flask server need to serve them somehow but as of right now, your server is not serving it properly, hence the `the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"` error. I don't have any experience with Flask unfortunately. You can always use Vue as a CDN if you want only a small piece of it, if you want to go all-in on Vue, using a webpack/vite config is still the way to go. What is your Flask server doing there exactly?

Comment: In the case of the question - nothing, it's just a toy example. But I wanted to see if I could simply import a node_module like I would any of my own modules. I mean, I can still make it work globally using CDN for the npm package, but I wanted to see if the import way was possible.

Comment: Depends if Flask is able to run an NPM module pretty much. Maybe, I don't know (but probably cannot out of the box).

Answer (score 0):

Tried to post a comment but wouldn’t let me. What other errors are you getting when you change the path?

Comment: Should be able to work fine: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @kissu I was below the 50 points at the time of this post.

Thank you though!